# Newer three.js version brakes light reflection on mesh

Tags: javascript, three.js

I recently upgraded from three.js version r110 to r124 because I needed some new features in r124. However now my meshes don't reflect light the way they used to, everything looks different!

**Does anyone know what changed between these versions that would have this effect and how I can undo it without reverting to the older version?**

Here are some photos to show what i'm talking about... You can see in picture **ONE** (r110) the light clearly reflects off the cylinder but in picture **TWO** (r124) the effect is not clear at all!

It's a little difficult to share the code here because the example is part of a large project but the only thing that has changed between these two photos is the three.js version number. In both photos I am using black **standard material** and a white **point light**.

**ONE**

[image]

**TWO**

[image]

Comment: You should probably mention what materials and light you are using. You can view all the changes between each version on the [releases page](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/releases) or it may be easier by taking a look at the [migration guide](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/Migration-Guide). After having a quick look, I did notice that they "Changed roughness and metalness default values." on MeshStandardMaterial in release 112 ([migraton guide here](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/Migration-Guide#r111--r112))),

Comment: @2pha okay that's very useful thanks! I am using standard material with a point light. The material colour is black and the light colour is white.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my comment...
The roughness and metalness default values for MeshStandardMaterial were [changed in r112](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/Migration-Guide#r111--r112).

So setting your material roughness and metalness to the values that were previously the defaults "0.5" should produce a material that looks the same as pre r112.

Comment: The roughness is behaving as expected with a value between 0 and 1. I found the best value to be 0.5 as per the old default. Docs: https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/materials/MeshStandardMaterial.roughness

Comment: However the metalness is behaving strangely... the docs suggest that it should be a value between 0 and 1 also but it seems happy to accept any numeric value. Docs: https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/materials/MeshStandardMaterial.metalness

Comment: Moreover the metalness is acting in the opposite way I would expect... lower values create a more metallic look and higher values reduce it. I found -10 to be the closest to what I had before... very strange!

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer did not help in my case. I have a number of `THREE.PointLight`s. After updating, objects seemed to no longer reflect the light coming from these.

I had to decrease the `decay` setting of the lights to `0.01` (down from `4`)